# In Jenkins Pipeline why two credentials needed at a time?

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline, ssh-agent

I want to connect from Jenkins agent to remote server via SSH and execute the commands. Exactly like said [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-agent/):

```
sshagent (credentials: ['deploy-dev']) {
    sh 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l cloudbees 192.168.1.106 uname -a'
  }
```

But in example I see that they mention credentials from Jenkins and in the command again uses login: "-l cloudbees".

So my question is the following: 
what "credentials: ['deploy-dev']" is used for then?

Answer (score 1):

Well, answering my own question :-)

SSH client needs credentials to connect to remote SSH daemon. Usually, they are either user/password or private SSH-key. 
What if you don't have neither of them at runtime moment?

This is what Jenkins Pipeline does:

1. It starts ssh-agent on Jenkins slave node. This is daemon that is
   listening for Unix-socket (this socket is stored in $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
   variable).
2. Then it adds (ssh-add) these credentials ('deploy-dev')
   to the running ssh-agent.  Next time, when you run command (in our
   case this is "ssh -l cloudbees 192.168.1.106" it fetches private
   SSH-key from ssh-agent

So eventually it will connect as user cloudbees but key will be fetched from ssh-agent. If you use plain credentials - maybe -l cloudbees is not needed at all. Not sure.

Some [useful link](http://blog.joncairns.com/2013/12/understanding-ssh-agent-and-ssh-add/) at your service.